# SD card won't mount (or even be recognized) after resuming from suspend

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, lenovo, sd-card

My 32GB SD card (FAT32) does not have any problem mounting perfectly if my laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04) never goes into suspend (after I close its lid).

But once I re-open the lid, retyping my password to login and resume working as before, the SD card vanishes, as if nothing was ever mounted... Pulling it out then re-inserting it doen't resolve the problem. I have to power of my laptop completely before the card is recognized and mounted again.

I have Windows 8.1 running on the same laptop (Lenovo Y50-70, dual-boot) and it has no such problem whatsoever, so this is unlikely to be a hardware problem. This points towards more like a driver bug in Ubuntu 14.04.

Is this a known issue? If so, do you know of any way to workaround it? (short of the aforementioned power-off)

Comment: BTW, restarting to Windows 8.1, accessing the SD card from there (mounts perfectly!), then restarting to Ubuntu, doesn't solve the problem. So, unfortunately, this cannot be a workaround. The only workaround currently is to power off the laptop completely, then power on to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro with Ubuntu 16.04. It would be great to have this fixed.